# Sharing multiple files between apps using UIActivityViewController in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have two applications named *App_A* and *App_B*. I have a `UIActivityViewController` to share a single or a group of files:

```
NSArray *itemsToShare = [self getItemsToShare]; // returns list with NSUrl objects
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
// presenting controller
```

When prompted, the popover contains *App_B* in the list. But when I select an *App_B* icon, I receive only the first url from the `itemsToShare` list in my `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method in the *App_B* delegate. Also, the Documents/Inbox folder contains only one file no matter how many files I try to share.

Why does the `UIActivityViewController` send only one file? Is this the normal behaviour, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to communicate info to another app. In your case, you have decided to use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. In that case, yes, this is only for handing one object to other app. It is intended for letting the user copy a file from the current app to the other app's inbox.

Comment: So, even if I send to UIActivityViewController a list of files, it will always activate a receiver application only with one?

Comment: If you do it the way you're doing, sure. Try it with iBooks. But look, just look at the method signature: it takes a URL, not an array.

Comment: I saw it, but it is a bit confusing when you are performing some activity with a couple of files and you doesn't receive all of them in target app. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Well, as I said, there are _other_ ways to share info between apps. You have chosen one that is about _copying one file_. If you don't like that way, use one of the other ways.